# Machine Learning - gradient descent

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-regression

In Machine Learning, for linear regression we plot a graph for coefficient and cost function to look at the global minimum. How to plot the same graph in case of multivariate linear regression with multiple coefficient and cost? Is it possible to visualise for multiple features?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're referring to simple OLS regression, you will be solving the same minimisation problem as in Andrew Ng's infamous linear regression via SGD. In both cases, the optimisation criterion (MSE) and underlying mathematical structure is the same:

$$(\beta_0,\beta_1,\cdots,\beta_p)^T = \underset{\beta_0,\beta_1,\cdots,\beta_p}{\arg \min}  \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( y_i - \beta_0 - \sum_{j=1}^p \beta_j x_{ij} \right)^2 $$

The only thing that changes is the minimisation method, partial derivatives in the former and stochastic gradient descent in the latter scenario. So, for the things that you're asking, nothing is different between the two schools.

Comment: Thank you. I got it.
Suppose, for example in linear regression, we have one features x1 (Assume x0 = 1). We can plot a graph for x and the y (hypotheses). How is it possible in the case of multiple features? Can we plot for graph for more than two  features (x1, x2, x3,....xn)?

Comment: Yes, but not in two dimensions. You'd have to find a specialised tool for plotting multivariable functions. I would suggest [Wolfram Mathematica](https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/PlottingAndGraphics.html).